# how to show the character that come several time in string?

Tags: c++, string

Is there anyway to show that character s appears 5 times in the string is there any function to sort out the character and than show us that the character appears 5 or 6 times in the string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main(){
using namespace std;
string a="hello how are you"
//now i want to show the l character appears several time.
//and i need help here.

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? We can give advice and help, once we see some effort on your part. You have coded the main but no attempt on the actual problem

Comment: i dont have an idea thats why i came here what to do next

Comment: now i get the idea that is count function the dude below just answer

Comment: for more familarity, please read http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html

Comment: ok i am going to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep counting using a pointer until nul character is reached and keep increasing an integer on successful comparison.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main(){
using namespace std;
string a="hello how are you";
char *p = &a[0];
int c = 0;
do
{   
    if(*p == 'l')
    c++;
}while(*p++);
cout << c;
}
```

Comment: you are storing refrecnce than you are comparing each chracter

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

```
int lcount = std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), 'l');
```

Comment: thats good count() function now i am going to try

Answer (score 1):

You can walk over any container, including a string and do what you like with it.
You could count how many instances of each character. You may want to consider ignoring whitespace.

```
std::string a("hello how are you");
std::map<char,int> count;
for(auto c : a)
{
    ++count[c];
}
```